# Set maxDate in the datepicker using Moment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

Depending on the year selected in the dropdown, I need to set the date picker `minDate` and `MaxDate`. MinDate can only be `Jan/01/{selectedYear}` and MaxDate should be `Dec/01/{selectedYear}`

I tried below. But doesn't seem to work:

```
MinDate = moment().format(`01/01/${selectedYear}`);
MaxDate = moment().format(`02/01/${selectedYear}`);
```

Output looks like:

> MinDate 01/01/2020 & MaxDate 02/01/2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get your point.
Can you please provide us your code? or maybe in a snippet or something.

And also, should MinDate & MaxDate be strings or Dates?

---

Do you want the output to be as follwing?

if selected year = 2020

MinDate: Jan/01/2020 & MaxDate: Dec/01/2020

if so, then you need to use this:

```js
let selectedYear = 2020; //or "2020"

//using moment
let minDate = moment().month(0).format(`MMM/01/${selectedYear}`); //you can also manipulate the day via moment
let maxDate = moment().month(11).date(1).format(`MMM/DD/${selectedYear}`);

console.log('minDate: ', minDate);
console.log('maxDate: ', maxDate);


//although you can do the stuff above without Moment:
let minDate0 = `Jan/01/${selectedYear}`;
let maxDate0 = `Dec/01/${selectedYear}`;

console.log('minDate (without moment): ', minDate0);
console.log('maxDate (without moment): ', maxDate0);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```